# Does exists any method which I can call before gesturerecognizer's method will be called?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a button whith UIPanGestureRecognizer. I want to determine the direction of finger like this:

```
if (sqrt(translation.x * translation.x) / sqrt(translation.y * translation.y) < 1)
    {
        isHorizontalScroll = YES;

    }
    else
    {
        isHorizontalScroll = NO;
    }
```

before recognizer's method will be called.

Does anybody know the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use touchesbegan,touchesmoved, touchesEnd

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, it sounds like you should be doing that check in the gesture recognizer when the gesture is in the UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan state. For example:

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    CGPoint translation = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:self.view];    

    switch (sender.state) {

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:

            if (sqrt(translation.x * translation.x) / sqrt(translation.y * translation.y) < 1)
                isHorizontalScroll = YES;
            else
                isHorizontalScroll = NO;

            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:

            ...
```

Comment: The problem is that I have to know the direction before handlePan will be called

Answer (score 1):

Actually the concrete implementation is up to you. To do this you have at least 3 leverages:

1. Use gesture recognizers.
2. Reimplement UIResponder's methods:

   ```
   – touchesBegan:withEvent:

   – touchesMoved:withEvent:

   – touchesEnded:withEvent:
   ```
3. Reimplement UIWindow's method:

   ```
   – (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event
   ```